# Android Google Places API on Lollipop and below

Tags: java, android, google-places-api, google-places

Does Google Places API work on Android Lollipop and below?
Because some phones with my app that uses Google Places gave this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places
java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.forName()Class.java:324
md5b74118df040d8158864d95fd3b66e81d.MainActivity.n_onResume(Native Method)
md5b74118df040d8158864d95fd3b66e81d.MainActivity.onResume()MainActivity.java:52
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume()Instrumentation.java:1281
android.app.Activity.performResume()Activity.java:6320
android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity()ActivityThread.java:3110
android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity()ActivityThread.java:3152
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity()ActivityThread.java:2495
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage()ActivityThread.java:1354
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage()Handler.java:102
android.os.Looper.loop()Looper.java:148
android.app.ActivityThread.main()ActivityThread.java:5443
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run()ZygoteInit.java:728
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main()ZygoteInit.java:618
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/expand/e7a5152a-8805-4bc2-8125-c715c5d4ff20/app/torathamachane.torathamachane-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/expand/e7a5152a-8805-4bc2-8125-c715c5d4ff20/app/torathamachane.torathamachane-2/lib/arm, /mnt/expand/e7a5152a-8805-4bc2-8125-c715c5d4ff20/app/torathamachane.torathamachane-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Comment: 1. clean and rebuild your project.     2. close and reopen your project.      one of them should fix your problem I guess

Comment: @ash12 On my phone it works. Only when I released and distributed it, a number of people, which have Lollipop and below, said that the app crashed.

Comment: DOes it have google play services installed?

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

One Reason of your problem can be 'You upgraded your google play service version in your dependency'

> In 9.0.2, the 'places' library was inside 'location' library. In 9.2.0, you need to add 'places' library as dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.0'
```

> Also,for play service 9.2.0 places import has changed from

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.places;
```

to

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
```

or you need all places folder

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.*;
```

Comment: I think I have the updated version. If not, how does it work on some devices?

Comment: please check again in your dependency because your log is clearly saying that it doesn't have the com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place; class